# How do I download the object that chrome.devtools.network.getHAR returns as a .har?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am using `chrome.devtools.network.getHAR` to get the har log from a site. However, I can't figure out how to convert it into a proper .har file and download it. I can use `JSON.stringify(harLog)`, convert to a BLOB, download the file, and view it as JSON, but I want to be able to download the file and be able to open the .har file with a .har viewer(like chrome network tab) from the downloads folder.

Here is the code that I have thus far:

```js
chrome.devtools.network.getHAR(
        function (harLog) {

            let harBLOB = new Blob([harLog]);

            let url = URL.createObjectURL(harBLOB);

            chrome.downloads.download({
                url: url,
                filename: "test.har"
            });
        });
```

With that code, it downloads a text file with the following content;

```
[object Object]
```

## Solution

After viewing a .har file generated from chrome dev tools I noticed that it followed the following format

```
{
  "log": {
    "version": "1.2",
    "creator": {
      ...
    },
  ...
}
```

whereas JSON.stringify(harLog) would give me

```
{
  "version": "1.2",
    "creator": {
      ...
    },
  ...
}
```

After I assigned the harLog object to the key: **log** of an object and stringified it, I was able to download import the file into chrome dev tools network tab.

### Working code

```js
chrome.devtools.network.getHAR(
        function (harLog) {
            let updatedHarLog = {};
            updatedHarLog.log = harLog;

            let harBLOB = new Blob([JSON.stringify(updatedHarLog)]);

            let url = URL.createObjectURL(harBLOB);

            chrome.downloads.download({
                url: url,
                filename: "test"
            });
        }
    );
```

Comment: Your code is actually missing JSON.stringify which is why you see `[object Object]`.

Comment: I don't want to download it as JSON, I want to download the file in the .har format

Comment: Add a Javascript tag to your question to get more views.

Comment: Just use JSON.stringify and everything will be fine :-) It won't change the "format".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) for guiding me in the right direction with `JSON.stringify()`

## Solution

After viewing a .har file generated from chrome dev tools I noticed that it followed the following format

```
{
  "log": {
    "version": "1.2",
    "creator": {
      ...
    },
  ...
}
```

whereas JSON.stringify(harLog) would give me

```
{
  "version": "1.2",
    "creator": {
      ...
    },
  ...
}
```

After I assigned the harLog object to the key: **log** of an object and stringified it, I was able to download import the file into chrome dev tools network tab.

### Working code

```js
chrome.devtools.network.getHAR(
        function (harLog) {
            let updatedHarLog = {};
            updatedHarLog.log = harLog;

            let harBLOB = new Blob([JSON.stringify(updatedHarLog)]);

            let url = URL.createObjectURL(harBLOB);

            chrome.downloads.download({
                url: url,
                filename: "test"
            });
        }
    );
```